# How to open a pdf file in cocos2d-x project?

Tags: android, ios, cocos2d-x

I want to open a file (pdf file to be exact) in iOS and Android through my cocos2d-x Project. It is to serve as help in my game. Is there any way to do so. I found we can open it in webview but how to do so on both iOS and android?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is no! `Cocos2d` family does not natively support `PDF`.

However, you can use open source C++ libraries to convert `PDF` to `PNG` on fly and load it as a texture in `cocos2d-x`.

My recommendation is to covert `pdf` to `png` on a PC and load `png` in `cocos2d-x`.

Comment: Hey. I did thought of the same but have one issue. I am to download that pdf from the internet on first login. Any other way around?

Comment: Not other than what I explained in the answer. You need to covert PDF to image using an open-source library like this: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php

Answer (score 0):

I did it using WebView both on Android and iOS. Also @kasra was correct and his way too works as a solution.